# Excel range not increasing

Tags: excel

I have the following formula:

=IF($L$12=3,$L3,IF($L$12>3,0,IF($L$12<3,B$3+$L15)))

When I copy it over, I want the 3 in L3 and the 15 in L15 to increase, but they stay the same. They increase when I copy down, but I need to copy to the side. Is there a way to make that work?

The unmarked 3s following the L12 references also lock, and Excel gives me an error when I try to add the $. Though in this case I want them locked anyway, I would also like to know if I can change that, if any potential solution for that is different than the one above.

Comment: The 3s are not references to cells so you cannot use a $ for them, you do not need to anyway as they are more or less locked by definition.

Making the other references (like $L15) behave the way you want them to will be quite difficult. I think you may not like the formula that is needed for that, if such a formula is possible. There may be a way to create a function in VBA that does what you would like it to do, but I do not know if you have experience with VBA.

Comment: You need combination of `INDIRECT()` and `COLUMN()` to make `$L15` change to `$L16` when copied sideways.

Answer (score 0):

The Comment from @[zx8754](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680068/zx8754):

> You need combination of INDIRECT() and COLUMN() to make $L15 change to $L16 when copied sideways.

may be as much of an answer as is possible without further details, which are unlikely to be forthcoming from an OP who is apparently not a user here nor registered elsewhere on SE.